# Текст при вставке в форму виден с конца строки

Tags: html, css, form

Можно ли сделать чтобы при вставке в форму текст показывался не с конца строки,а с ее начала?
То есть,например когда вставляем ссылку типа `https://web.postman.co/build/workspace`, в форме я вижу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А надо вот так:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто при изменении значения `input`-а, установите каретку в начало:

```html
<input type="text"> - обычный input
<br><br>
<input type="text" oninput="this.setSelectionRange(0,0);"> - с фокусом в начале
<br><br>
<i>Длинный текст для копирования и вставки</i>
```

*Хотя, при потере фокуса, строка сама занимает нужное положение.*

Comment: Представляю боль юзера, который захочет это отредактировать)

Comment: @vp_arth: жизнь вообще такая, да... :)

Comment: @vp_arth ну в любом случае редактировать url,что с той стороны,что с обратной,будет болезненным)

Comment: @Yozhik, с вами никогда не делились ссылками с инструкцией вроде "удалите пробелы"?

Comment: @vp_arth: нужно делиться ссылками там, где не нужно в них пробелы вставлять ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Что-то оно не скроллится по setSelectionRange без blur)

```js
document.querySelector('input')
  .addEventListener('paste', function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      this.blur();
      this.focus();
    });    
  })
```

```html
<input type=text>
```

Comment: Раньше, ещё на WinXP, во всех браузерах нормально работало `onpaste`, без ограничений. Сейчас поломали что-то...